# Must the input height of a 1D CNN be constant?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently doing my honours research project on online/dynamic signature verification. I am using the SVC 2004 dataset (Task 2). I have done the following data processing:

```
def load_dataset_normalized(path):
file_names = os.listdir(path)

num_of_persons = len(file_names)

initial_starting_point = np.zeros(np.shape([7]))

x_dataset = []
y_dataset = []

for infile in file_names:
    full_file_name = os.path.join(path, infile)
    file = open(full_file_name, "r")
    file_lines = file.readlines()

    num_of_points = int(file_lines[0])

    x = []
    y = []
    time_stamp = []
    button_status = []
    azimuth_angles = []
    altitude = []
    pressure = []

    for idx, line in enumerate(file_lines[1:]):
        idx+=1
        nums = line.split(' ')

        if idx == 1:
            nums[2] = 0
            initial_starting_point = nums

            x.append(int(nums[0]))
            y.append(int(nums[1]))
            time_stamp.append(0)
            button_status.append(int(nums[3]))
            azimuth_angles.append(int(nums[4]))
            altitude.append(int(nums[5]))
            pressure.append(int(nums[6]))

        else:
            x.append(int(nums[0]))
            y.append(int(nums[1]))
            time_stamp.append(10)
            button_status.append(int(nums[3]))
            azimuth_angles.append(int(nums[4]))
            altitude.append(int(nums[5]))
            pressure.append(int(nums[6]))

    max_x = max(x)
    max_y = max(y)
    max_azimuth_angle = max(azimuth_angles)
    max_altitude = max(altitude)
    max_pressure = max(pressure)

    min_x = min(x)
    min_y = min(y)
    min_azimuth_angle = min(azimuth_angles)
    min_altitude = min(altitude)
    min_pressure = min(pressure)

    #Alignment normalization:
    for i in range(num_of_points):
        x[i] -= int(initial_starting_point[0])
        y[i] -= int(initial_starting_point[1])
        azimuth_angles[i] -= int(initial_starting_point[4])
        altitude[i] -= int(initial_starting_point[5])
        pressure[i] -= int(initial_starting_point[6])

    #Size normalization
    for i in range(num_of_points):
        x[i] = ((x[i] - max_x) / (min_x - max_x))
        y[i] = ((y[i] - max_y) / (min_y - max_y))
        azimuth_angles[i] = ((azimuth_angles[i] - max_azimuth_angle) / (min_azimuth_angle - max_azimuth_angle))
        altitude[i] = ((altitude[i] - max_altitude) / (min_altitude - max_altitude))
        pressure[i] = ((pressure[i] - max_pressure) / (min_pressure - max_pressure))

    #data points to dataset
    x_line = []
    for i in range (num_of_points):
        x_line.append([x[i], y[i], time_stamp[i], button_status[i], azimuth_angles[i], altitude[i], pressure[i]])

        if i == num_of_points-1:
            x_dataset.append(x_line)

    infile_without_extension = infile.replace('.TXT','')
    index_of_s = infile_without_extension.find("S")
    index_of_num = index_of_s + 1
    sig_ID = int(infile_without_extension[index_of_num:])
    if sig_ID < 21:
        y_dataset.append([1,0])
    else:
        y_dataset.append([0,1])

x_dataset = np.asarray(x_dataset)
y_dataset = np.asarray(y_dataset)
return x_dataset, y_dataset
```

I also have another method that takes the values as they are in the text file and created an "original" dataset.

Now, the aim of my research is to create a CRNN (convolutional recurrent neural network) that can identify if a signature is authentic or forged. Here is the code for the model:

```
class crnn_model:
def __init__(self, trainX, trainy, testX, testy, optimizer_method):
    self.trainX = trainX
    self.trainy = trainy
    self.testX = testX
    self.testy = testy

    self.evaluate_model(optimizer_method)

def evaluate_model(self, optimizer_method):
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 40, 10
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = len(self.trainX), 7, 2
    print(n_timesteps)
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), use_bias=True))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(2, input_shape=[30592,1], return_sequences=True))
    model.summary()

    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer_method, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    #fit model
    model.fit(self.trainX, self.trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

    # evaluate model
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(self.testX, self.testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    return accuracy
```

Here is the problem I am having: the number of points used to store each signature is different, hence making the input height of the input matrix vary from one signature to the next. Must I now force the dataset to some uniform/constant number of points?

Much appreciated for your time.

Comment: In many problems, you would solve your issue with padding. Find the max number of input nodes per batch (or per dataset), and pad your smaller input up to that value. Typically the padded value would be zero, so that it effectively does not "train" - but weighted padding might be a thing. I normally use PyTorch, but I think Keras also has a ZeroPadding type-of layer.

Comment: About your second question: yes it can be "valid". But might be better to ask another question about this with actual code and error traces.