# Is it possible to use the output of a flatten layer of a CNN to be the input of a RNN?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently doing my honours research project on online/dynamic signature verification. I am using the SVC 2004 dataset (Task 2). The aim of my research is to create a CRNN (convolutional recurrent neural network) that can identify if a signature is authentic or forged. Here is the code for the model: (my data preprocessing can be found here: [Data preprocessing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759627/must-the-input-height-of-a-1d-cnn-be-constant)

```
class crnn_model:
def __init__(self, trainX, trainy, testX, testy, optimizer_method):
   self.trainX = trainX
   self.trainy = trainy
   self.testX = testX
   self.testy = testy

   self.evaluate_model(optimizer_method)

def evaluate_model(self, optimizer_method):
    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 40, 10
    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = len(self.trainX), 7, 2
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), use_bias=True))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(2, input_shape=[30592,1], return_sequences=True))
    model.summary()

    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer_method, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    #fit model
    model.fit(self.trainX, self.trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)

    #evaluate model
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(self.testX, self.testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    return accuracy
```

This is not my final code, however I come across the following error:

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Much appreciated for your time and any tips on RNNs or CNNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flatten` converts a tensor of shape `(batch_size, timesteps, features)` to `(batch_size, timesteps*features)` which is why you are getting the error `found ndim=2`. Depending on what you are trying to achieve you might:

- Remove `Flatten` to pass the convolved learned features into an LSTM, or
- `Reshape` the flattened tensor to `(batch_size, timesteps*features, 1)` essentially saying every timestep is a single feature.

In either case the LSTM expects a tensor of rank 3. But wait, just because you reshape doesn't mean it is correct, it all depends on what you are trying to achieve and how the information flow / computation graph of the network should look like.

Comment: Your first solution solved the error mentioned above @nuric, however, I got the following error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (960, 1)